# how to define relations between many tables while I have multiple columns primary key?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have one table its name is (DataInfo) that contains data information `"this table will be linked to every table in the database"`

```
DataID,DataName
```

and I have two another tables

first one is :

```
DataID,CurrencyID,CurrencyName
```

Second one is :

```
DataID,TransID,TransDec,TransAmount,CurrencyID
```

my question is how to define the relations between these tables ?

Comment: I didn't understand what are you trying to do, but generally if you want "DataInfo" to be linked to every table in your database then the PrimaryKey (DataID) should be a ForeignKey in all the other tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataID will be the foreign key for two tables besides "DataInfo". For first table CurrencyID will be the primary key and DataID will be foreign key. For second table TransID will be the primary key and DataID and CurrencyID will be the foreign key. Both table need not have a tuple of columns as their primary key as TransID will be unique for every transaction and so will be CurrencyID for each currency